# Using Orderby and meta_value_num to order numbers first then strings

Tags: order

I have a list of products, each with a price in a custom field stored as text such as "2.50" or "5.00" and I am displaying them on the page with a custom query that sorts by the price:

```
    if(!$wp_query) {
        global $wp_query;
    }

    $args = array(
        'meta_key' => 'price',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    query_posts( array_merge( $args , $wp_query->query ) );
```

This works fine for the prices, but some prices are "POA" and I would like to show them last, however the above orders in such a way that "POA" is shown first.

Is there any way to alter this, or a quick hack I could use to sort the array afterwards and put any "POA" prices last?

Comment: try changing `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
` to `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num meta_value',`

Comment: Thanks but that does not work :(

Comment: Aha! But the other way around does work, `meta_value meta_value_num` ! Thanks! Do you want to write up an answer so I can vote it up?

Comment: posted as an answer for people who don't read comments.

Comment: POA means "price on asking" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_on_application

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `OrderBy` argument can take more then one parameter so the solution was to change :

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
```

to:

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value meta_value_num',
```

Comment: This just sorts alphabetically, as the second parameter is a no-op, sorting on the same field to no effect. To do this so that the numbers sort numerically and the alphas alphabetically you'd have to use a filter to customize the orderby to use some sort of SQL casing, eg `ORDER BY CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_value RLIKE '^[0-9]' THEN '' ELSE wp_postmeta.meta_value END ASC, wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC`

Comment: @bonger Thank you! Your solution is complete solution for this problem. And here is rest of the code where your query is placed.
I am going to post it as answer for new visitors.

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution by combining code by @bonger and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084199/wordpress-query-order-by-case-when

And it works well.

**Function**

```
function filter_case($orderby = '') {
  $orderby .= "CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_value RLIKE '^[0-9]' THEN '' ELSE wp_postmeta.meta_value END ASC, wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC";
  return $orderby;
}
```

**Before Query**

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'filter_case' );

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'filter_case' );
```