# How to order posts by alphabet with numbers at the end

Tags: order

How to order posts by alphabet with numbers at the end.

```
  $params = array(
    'limit' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
  );
```

I have a list of businesses (Pods framework post type) and they are in ordered by name. Some business names have a number in them, such as 7-11 and the client wants those to be at the end, so `a->z->0->9` I guess. How would I go about this?

**Actual**

```
7-11,
Apple store,
Zebra store
```

**Desired**

```
Apple store,
Zebra store,
7-11
```

Comment: did you see this post?  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45413/using-orderby-and-meta-value-num-to-order-numbers-first-then-strings

Comment: Actually, I believe this one is more in line with what you need to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861852/sort-mysql-results-alphabetically-but-with-numbers-last You might have to build your own sql query however, if the provided filter hooks don't allow you this hack...

Answer (score 0):

With some help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861852/sort-mysql-results-alphabetically-but-with-numbers-last) and this [post](http://matthewturland.com/2008/11/05/natural-ordering-in-mysql/) I managed to get your desired sorting hooking into the [`posts_orderby`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby) filter.

You would need to add some additional check so this only affects *your* post type and on *your* page of choice but this snippet gives you the required statement to get the

```
Apple store
Zebra store
7-11
```

posts sorting, provided their slug is

```
apple-store
zebra-store
7-11
```

since I order by `post_name` which is the post's `slug`

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby' , 'wpse_custom_orderby_statement' );
function wpse_custom_orderby_statement( $orderby ) {

  $orderby = " post_name+0<>0 ASC, post_name+0, post_name";

  return $orderby;
}
```